# Datepicker Region dd/mm/yyyy MVC

Tags: html, mvc, datetime, annotation

Buenos estimados:
Tengo un tema con la validacion de la Fecha de Nacimiento,

1. tengo configurado el datepicker para que muestre la fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy
   Pero cuando la ingreso en el Input, salta la validacion de las Data Annotations y me valida como mm/dd/yyyy.
   Intente cambiarlo en webconfig con un formato:
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]

Pero nada sirve.. es mas ahora termine optando por mostrar una Fecha "Octubre/31/2017" y me lo permite aun teniendo las data Anotations.

Comment: Hola yo tuve el mismo problema pero lo solucione con esto (sigue al pie de la letra):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9s4-gzO1bpNMUQwRGlEMHI4T0E comenta si lo solucionaste saludos: